# Git working directory and copying/moving it around

Tags: git

Say I have created local repo or cloned a remote repo to my local directory `c:\Tenerife\MyRepo`. I have there:

```
.git              <-- Subdirectory with some magic stuff inside.
README.md         <-- My file that will work on. I will maybe add more files later.
```

So, what can I do with this directory?

1. Are there any cases when I will have to look inside .git subdirectory or change there something?
2. Can I move this directory to any other place? Can I be sure that this action will not leave any trace on what I was doing, on the state of my branches, commits, PRs, granted rights, whatever?
3. Can I copy (i.e. duplicate) this directory to some other place? Will this action be any different from making an independent cloning?
4. Is it right that all files that belong to this repository **are in this subdirectory only**? That there no tricks (submodules, whatever) that any file will be located elsewhere?
5. If I specify something in `.gitignore`, would that be the same **from the Git point of view** as if those files are not existing at all? I.e. their presence/absence will no affect any activity of Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any cases when I will have to look inside .git subdirectory or change there something?

there are a few special file inside this directory which you can modify (if you know what you are doing), They are mostly located in the `.git/info`, and `.git/hooks`. You can also modify `.git/config`.

> Can I move this directory to any other place? Can I be sure that this action will not leave any trace on what I was doing, on the state of my branches, commits, PRs, granted rights, whatever?

You can freely move the whole worktree with the .git subdirectory to any place with no problems. The only issue could be if you have absolute symbolic links in your sources which point to the current location. Don't have them, replace with relative.

You can move just the  `.git` subdirectory,  but you would need do do something special to have git still functional. Mainly, you would need to define the GIT_DIR env variable to point to the new location of the `.git` directory or use `--git-dir=new-location` for every git command.

> Can I copy (i.e. duplicate) this directory to some other place? Will this action be any different from making an independent cloning?

You can copy the worktree with the .git repo to any place. There are some differences from cloning. Clone sets up your remote repositories for push/pull. If you copy, you would need to do it manually.

> Is it right that all files that belong to this repository are in this subdirectory only? That there no tricks (submodules, whatever) that any file will be located elsewhere?

The `.git` subdirectory contains data which represents every file in the repository and all its versions. In regular git there are no source controlled files which could be located outside of the repository. In git `lfs` though the files can be located at arbitrary locations and the git repository contains references to them. Submodules are just incorporated stand-alone git repositories. They have their own `.git` equivalents.

> If I specify something in .gitignore, would that be the same from the Git point of view as if those files are not existing at all? I.e. their presence/absence will no affect any activity of Git?

.gitignore is only used to prevent git from adding/viewing a set of untracked files. It does not matter if the untracked file you listed is missing or not. Git will not report it in any case.

Comment: whoever downgraded, please provide a constructive reason for it.

Comment: Hopeless. They never do this.

Comment: > Clone sets up your remote repositories for push/pull.
Hm. After duplicating local dir, any links to remote repo should be the same.. Nothing happened with the remote. How duplication differs from moving?

Comment: clone creates origin which points to the directory you cloned from. Copy keeps whatever was there int he first place. So, you do not have set up connection to the origin of copy. But you can still be connected to what the copied dir was connected to.

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) You can look and modify, but probably you can achieve everything with git commands.

ad 2) Yes you can move. No changes are automatically applied to the repository if your move tool messes something - you have to commit it.

ad 3) Copping will copy also your not pushed changes.  Cloning will just get a fresh copy from the remote repo.

ad 5) Yes until files will be created. When files will be created the behavior of git add command will be different depending on if the files hadn't existed before or were specified in .gitignore.